# import from CSV to Postgres is missing some rows in python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, import, django-celery

I have been trying to import a large scale data from csv to Postgres after every 10mins.
With the help of celery I have scheduled few jobs parallelly.

No. of rows in csv are not matching after import into postgres.

I've been writing CSVs into db with `df.to_sql()` method and it is not throwing any error but still some rows are missing in DB.

According to my observance the increasing size of table is leading to missing rows.

Is it Postgres limit?
or is it the overlapping schedule of jobs which is causing locks or anything?

Comment: Is CSV file well-formatted?

Comment: yes, when writing the same csv of my local system it is not missing any row, but on server where multiple jobs are parallelly running its skipping few rows sometimes(not every time)

Comment: I would say this points to your parallelization code not properly selecting the boundaries for the separate jobs.

Comment: If the file contains newlines inside quotes, the number of lines won't be the same as the number of rows.  If that isn't it, it is probably your code, as PostgreSQL is pretty robust about this.

Comment: My code is working perfectly fine When running it on local with hundreds of files, but skipping few rows when deployed on server. Logged the number of rows when reading into df. its reading all rows correctly, but dont know why it is skipping when writing into db !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the columns of my CSV file I had data in this format:

> "abc, xyz"

So, using `quotechar='"'` helped me to fix my issue.

Thank you all for your ideas and suggestions.